# Spring JPA H2 database get org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException Schema "MYSCHEMA" not found

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2, database-schema

I have my Spring boot JPA Entity defined as :

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "CAR", schema="MYSCHEMA") //DB2 requires schema so this works on DB2 but not on H2
//@Table(name = "CAR") // this works on H2 but not on DB2 as it requires schema
public class CarEntity implements Serializable {
...
```

The above works fine in DB2 but not in H2.

In application.properties, I have following settings:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:MYDB"
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

When I do maven>Install, I get error:
**org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
create table MYSCHEMA.CAR (...**
...

**Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "MYSCHEMA" not found; SQL statement:
public class CarEntity implements Serializable {
...**

I would expect that on H2, schema is created since I provide it in my `@Table` annotation but that is not happening.  What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to resolve this issue.
Since DB2 requires schema, I changed to following:

Mark entity with

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "CAR") 
public class CarEntity implements Serializable {
```

but for DB2 url add `:currentSchema=MY_SCHEMA;` to the end of spring datasource url like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://db2_server:port//MY_DB:currentSchema=MY_SCHEMA;
```

Imprtant to notice is ":" separator between MY_DB and currentSchema and the ";" at the end.

And for H2, I dont care about schema as it is in-memory database I just use to test of resulting endpoints, I dont have any schema indications neither above in my entity's @Table annotation nor in the datasource url:

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:MY_DB